# Understanding virtual interfaces with classes

Tags: system-verilog

I am studying SystemVerilog for verification purposes and stumbled upon virtual interfaces and classes. I am trying to set up an example where I define a `virtual interface` attribute in a class to be initialized through a method. It looks like this:

```
class myclass;

virtual interface my_intf val;
...

function void configure(virtual interface my_intf input_intf);
    val = input_intf;
endfunction
...
endclass
```

An object of this class is instantiated in a testbench that has the interface I intend to pass on to the object as an input.

```
module mytb(my_intf bus);
...

myclass c1;

initial
begin
    c1 = new;
    c1.configure(bus);
...
endmodule
```

What I am encountering is a warning at elaboration time that says `[related to c1.configure(bus)] formal and actual do not have assignment compatible data types (expecting datatype compatible with 'virtual interface my_intf' but found 'my_intf' instance instead`. Nevertheless, the simulation ends with success, and I made sure to follow the code presented in the course I am attending. Is there anything I am still missing or can I neglect this warning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have looked more into my code and found out that it had to do with the fact that the testbench uses a specific configuration of the interface defined through a `modport` and I had to make sure that I extended that to the class too. In short, the testbench receives a `my_intf.intf1 bus` interface and this caused the tool to complain as it was expecting `my_intf` but got `my_intf.intf1` instead.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You missing a lot of code, so it it difficult to figure out what is going one.
However, for references the following code works:

```
class myclass;
   virtual interface my_intf val;

   function void configure(virtual interface my_intf input_intf);
      val = input_intf;
   endfunction

endclass

module mytb(my_intf bus);
   myclass c1;

   initial
   begin
      c1 = new;
      c1.configure(bus);
   end
endmodule
     
interface my_intf;
endinterface
     
module top;
  my_intf intf();
  mytb mytb(intf);
endmodule
```

Few rules of thumb:

1. an interface must be defined as intercface..endinterface and it must be visible in all parts of compilation (can be declared after it is used, similarly to moduels). See code example.
2. the interface must be instantiated in a module, e.g. in module *top* of the example.

Note, similar issues as you described can happen if you incorrectly use compilation units.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with SystemVerilog, but I've just RFTM around and the right syntax is:

`virtual interface_name instance_name;`

So maybe you should try something like this:

```
virtual my_intf val;

function void configure(virtual my_intf val);
    this.val = val;
endfunction
...
endclass
```

See https://verificationguide.com/systemverilog/systemverilog-virtual-interface/#What_is_the_need_for_a_virtual_interface_in_SystemVerilog

Comment: keyword 'interface' is optional with virtual interfaces. check syntax carefully. The issue has nothing to do with bas syntax in any case.